# How can I check in Rails controller if InvalidAuthenticityToken error was raised from session expiry?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, cookies, redis, authenticity-token

I would like to be able to rescue this error and do stuff in some specific controllers, only if it was raised because of session expiry (set to 24h in `session_store.rb`).
Is there a way to know the difference between session expiry and an actual CSRF attack/missing authenticity token when raising this error?

I am currently using this configuration :

```rb
Rails.application.config.session_store :redis_store, redis_server: redis_url, expire_after: 24.hours
```

I am trying to understand the specifics of how the Rails server knows that the authenticity_token should be considered invalid.

I guess the information I miss is : where is the backend logic of comparison between

- the date of first response + cookie creation
- the date after expiry time (24h in my case)
  that checks that the cookie/session/token is not valid anymore ? Is that on Rails side ? On Redis side ? In the browser ?

I hope I could make my question clear enough !
Thanks :)

Comment: I have the same question, so I came across this. One thing I'll point out is that your CSRF auth tokens do not expire after 24 hours. Your session expiration time has nothing to do with the CSRF auth token expiry time. That is set elsewhere (if it can be configured at all, I've not looked).